# html treated as text in fullcalender version 5

Tags: javascript, html, fullcalendar-5

I have the following string for  event['title'] :

```
Consumer behaviors <br> Zero Waste Communities
```

it gets displayed as text in fullcalendar version 5.

How can I display this as html so the break works?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Taken from [this example](https://codepen.io/arshaw/pen/ExPXjpY?editable=true&editors=001)

Add to your calendar object:

```
eventContent: function(eventInfo) {
       return { html: eventInfo.event.title }
}
```

A full example calendar object including the snippet:

```
  var calendar = new FullCalendar.Calendar(calendarEl, {
    initialView: 'dayGridMonth',
    initialDate: '2020-06-07',
    events: [
      {
        title: '<strong>All Day<br> Event</strong>',
        start: '2020-06-01',
      }
    ],
    eventContent: function(eventInfo) {
      return { html: eventInfo.event.title }
    }
  });
```

Comment: thank you.  Unfortunately when you do that the text no longer stays in the box and now overflows instead of breaking inside the box. so if I have some text and then a < br> that works but when followed by a long string that part overflows the box instead of breaking

Comment: https://codepen.io/appleseeds/pen/eYBMzYx?editable=true&editors=001

Comment: Anyway can be fixed with css, hope this solves the question you asked

Comment: needed to add some css to .fc-event